# Glyphicon shows as box in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap, I am using glyphicon-log-in for log-in link in one of my apps.

The icon is not rendering properly.

Any idea to resolve it ?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="log"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not rendering properly?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks fine to me. 
Are you sure you have properly included bootstrap stylesheets in the `<head>` ?

Comment: Yeah, I found that the fonts were dislocated where bootstrap unable to identify.

Comment: Thanks for your time Aaron Ullal.

Comment: No problem! If it solved your issue you can mark it as correct answer =)